# Elegant way to static_assert() that a standard library container type is ordered?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, static-assert

In a templated function where one parameter is a standard library container of type `T`, can I easily statically assert that `T` is an ordered container?

Is there a more elegant way to do this than to do something type-specific, like test for the presence of a `hash_function()` function to distinguish between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` ?

Comment: Boost::container_traits looks like it would be hepful, but it is still "pending".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple one:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container>
struct is_ordered : std::false_type {};

template <> struct is_ordered<std::map>      : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ordered<std::set>      : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ordered<std::multimap> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ordered<std::multiset> : std::true_type {};
```

and then just `static_assert(is_ordered<Container>::value, "error")` to use it. It's pretty easy to extend to custom containers too: just add a line like the above.

If you don't want to use template-templates at the call site, you can always wrap it ala:

```
template <typename T> struct is_ordered_2 : std::false_type {};
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename... Ts>
struct is_ordered_2<Container<Ts...>> : is_ordered<Container> {};
```

and then you can use it either way.

Comment: This seems to be the best mix of succinctness in usage and ease of maintenance. Is there a form that will work in a compiler without support for variadic templates?

Comment: That I'm not sure. You would have to re-structure the internal `is_ordered` that's for sure. Perhaps you can pull it off using a type list from boost or something.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is pretty simple:

```
// default result
template<class T>constexpr bool IsOrdered(const T&) {return false;}

// now enumerate the ordered standard library types of interest:
template<class K, class T, class C, class A>
constexpr bool IsOrdered(const std::map<K,T,C,A>&) {return true;}
// ...remaining types...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with barring the use of a couple particular classes like `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set`, for example, you could use type traits in concert with `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

template <typename Container, typename T>
void func(Container<T> &c)
{
    // make sure that the provided container isn't a type we don't want!
    static_assert(!std::is_same<Container<T>, std::unordered_map<T>>::value);
    static_assert(!std::is_same<Container<T>, std::unordered_set<T>>::value);
}
```

I'm not sure whether this qualifies as "type-specific" or not based on your original question. You're not looking at the innards of the prohibited classes at all (like looking for a `hash_function()`, but this method would require you to enumerate the containers that you don't want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could (emphasis on could, cuz I don't think it is standard) do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_typedef_key_compare 
{
  // Types "yes" and "no" are guaranteed to have different sizes,
  // specifically sizeof(yes) == 1 and sizeof(no) == 2.
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(typename C::key_compare*);

  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

  // If the "sizeof" of the result of calling test<T>(0) would be equal to sizeof(yes),
  // the first overload worked and T has a nested type named foobar.
  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename T>
struct is_sorted_container
{
  static const bool value;
};

template <typename T>
const bool is_sorted_container<T>::value = has_typedef_key_compare<T>::value;
```

The rationale is that all sorted stl containers (that I looked at) have a key_compare function. Of course, this is NOT standard. This would NOT cover non-stl types. All in all, I don't like it, but I thought I'd post it as an interesting alternative.

How stl function (like std::upper_bound) cover this is to put the restriction of sorted iterator in the comments, and let the end user figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "NOT standard"? `key_compare` is one of the associative container requirements, so will be present in all standard associative containers, and any non-standard ones that claim to meet the requirements.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I meant it as there is nothing in the standard that says containers with key_compare are sorted containers, just that those containers currently have this. There is also nothing in the standard that says that unsorted containers don't, just just so happen to not have them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Mostly, I'm not sure if the "Associative containers" type is now and forever will be the only types that would apply to the user's dilemma.

Comment: MSVC defines key_compare for unordered_map as well, so this is not a good member to check